# read_delim seems unable to parse files with quotation mark?

Tags: r, readr

I have the following tab-delimited file that `read_delim` seems to fail because of the quotation mark.

```
8436127 "Baki-Pilsen" Brewery   "Baki-Pilsen" Brewery       40.32864    49.78044    P   PPLL    AZ                      0       -25 Asia/Baku   2012-12-17
```

(pastebin link to preserve tabs: http://pastebin.com/ZKkAZ9Fr)

```
read_tsv("read_delim_fail.txt", col_names = FALSE) # Fail to parse
```

This is especially puzzling because `read_delim`, `read_tsv` already specify `quote = "\t"`. What does it fail to parse?

Comment: `read.table` works

Comment: Yes, and `fread` too. Since I'm trying to move into the tidyverse, I'm wondering if it's possible to make this work with readr, or should I file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the `readr::read_*` family of functions to not use `"` to quote strings. To do that you override the default value for the `quote` parameter such as in:

```
read_tsv("read_delim_fail.txt", col_names = FALSE, quote="")
```